# Переменная socket удаляется перед ивентом disconnect Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

У меня случилась такая проблема, не знаю как её решить
Строю сервер для онлайн-игры на socket.io, когда игрок отключается, то переменная socket (там также находятся данные пользователя и id сокета) удаляется перед ивентом disconnect, а в disconnect у меня идёт удаление игрока из массивов, поэтому сервер не может удалить игрока, так как не знает его id подключения.
Как это исправить?

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('auth', (reqData) => {
            players[socket.id] = socket.player;
            socket.player = { array of player };
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            id = socket.id;
            player = socket.player;
            if (socket.player) {
                console.log(socket.player.name + ' disconnected')
                if (typeof players[id] != 'undefined') delete players[id]

            //  console.log(players)
            //  console.log(rooms)
            }
        }); });
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код,уверен так будет легче разобраться с проблемой

Comment: UPD: Показал в посте

Comment: Не понятно, каким образом переменная *socket удаляется перед ивентом disconnect*?

Comment: Вот я бы и хотел узнать почему.

Comment: Часто бывают такие моменты, когда в disconnect: socket = undefined